# How To target a particular window of particular tab and save source file in safari without disturbing other windows

Tags: safari, applescript

I am using Safari version 14.1.2 and macOS Mojave version 10.14.6
I am working with many windows in Safari as well as Google Chrome. I would like to routinely (certain time) refresh some particular tab of some particular window and to save it as HTML File without disturbing other windows.
The below code works up to 80% of my need. Whereas its brings the target window as frontmost window, which disturbs while working in another window.

```
set someurl to “Google.com”
tell application “Safari”
  set myID to id of window 1
  set myTab to current tab of window 1
  set thename to name of window 1
end tell


repeat
tell application “Safari”
  set index of window id myID to 1
  set URL of myTab to someurl
   if document 1 exists then
    set theDocumentTitle to the name of document 1
    set theDocumentSource to the source of document 1
     tell application “TextWrangler”
      set theNewDocument to make new document with properties {name:theDocumentTitle, text:theDocumentSource}
      set theDocumentsFolderPath to the path to desktop as text
      set theSaveFilePath to theDocumentsFolderPath & theDocumentTitle & “.html”
      save theNewDocument to file theSaveFilePath
      close theNewDocument
     end tell
  end if
end tell
delay 20
end repeat
```

Is there any script to fulfill my need for both Safari and Google Chrome?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,
John

Comment: You can use the **curl** shell command to achieve your goals. As for the universal solution for 2 browsers, the script should determine which one is the front one and get the **URL** and **name** of document of the current page in order to pass them to the curl command. TextWrangler is not needed at all.